# Test if property throws exception with nunit

Tags: c#, properties, delegates, c#-2.0, nunit-2.5

it seems there are no delegates to properties. Is there a convenient way to do the following?

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
       delegate
       {
           // Current is a property as we all know
           nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current;
       });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fast-forward four years and NUnit now supports this (current version is v2.6 - I've not checked which version this was introduced).

```
Assert.That(() => nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current,
    Throws.InvalidOperationException);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
    delegate { object current = nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current; });
```

Comment: @Anton Hi anton I would like to know is this the way to use to Test for readonly property of a class that is public ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try assigning it to a variable or try enumerating:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(delegate
{
    // Current is a property as we all know
    object current = nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not say:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(
    () => nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current);
```

Comment: You will still need to do an actual (throw away) assignment and keep the {}, so: (() => { var x = nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current; })

Comment: That doesn't compile. Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Follow up on @bytedev :
For clarity, a discard ( '_' ) can be used (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).
So the statement becomes:

`Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => { _ = nullNodeList.GetEnumerator().Current; });`